# android Intent.ACTION_VIEW crash when call market URL

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to create a feedback field for my application. I just want redirect the user to the market like this

```
String APP_MARKET_URL = "market://details?id=com.my.application"; 

Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(APP_MARKET_URL)); 
this.startActivity(intent);
```

But when i execute it i have this error:

```
02-13 11:07:33.147: W/dalvikvm(238): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
02-13 11:07:33.155: E/AndroidRuntime(238): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.picca.pointage.NoterApplication }
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2749)
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2855)
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:829)
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:190)
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3285)
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1640)
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-13 11:07:33.225: E/AndroidRuntime(238):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I use android 1.5. I did not put specific entry in the manifest.
Anyone have an idea or an other method for call my market page?

Comment: Is your activity NoterApplication registered in manifest file ??

Comment: have you declared permission in manifest file

Comment: Are you completely sure that you fire the intent you show here? `act=com.picca.pointage.NoterApplication` indicates that the intent that causes the crash has a completely different action *(not the VIEW action)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running this code on the emulator, you should know that there is no Android Market application on the emulator, so it will throw you this exception. There should be no problem on most of the real devices. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that crash on the emulator but not on device! Thx!

Comment: I know that's an old answer but i'm not sure it's complete. There are some android devices without a market (like kindle fire) so you have to check first if someone can receive your intent before starting it.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on a previous comment, you can check if the Intent can be resolved on the device before starting a new Activity with it using code like this:

```
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName cn = intent.resolveActivity(pm);
    if (cn != null) {
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following flat to your intent.

`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`